Pandoc styling of Default Paragraph and Body Text
I have the markdown file input.md:
---
title: My test document
---

## Section 1

Line 1.

Line 2.

Line 3.

## Section 2

Line 1.

Line 2.

Line 3.

I have a very simple reference.odt document.
I convert the markdown to ODT with:
pandoc input.md --reference-doc=reference.odt -o output.odt

Under both headings in the ODT document:

"Line 1." has a paragraph style of "Default Paragraph Style".
Subsequent lines have a paragraph style of "Body Text".

This makes the final document appear badly formatted.
I appreciate that I could change the styling of "Default Paragraph Style" in reference.odt, but that will have knock-on effects elsewhere, such as table of contents, etc.
I also appreciate that I could probably apply the "Body Text" style to a paragraph in the markdown, but that's not preferable, as it overcomplicates the markdown (which is supposed to be simple.)
Is there a way to instruct Pandoc to treat everything under a heading as "Body Text"?
If not, does anyone have any other solutions?
Thanks
I

A Lua filter could do this. The one below wraps all paragraphs such that a custom style is forced for all paragraph, thus overriding the default behavior of using a different style for the first paragraph in a section.
local paragraph_style = 'Text body'
function Para (p)
  return pandoc.Div({p}, {['custom-style'] = paragraph_style})
end

Use the filter by saving it to a file and passing it to pandoc via --lua-filter=/path/to/the/filter.lua.
